# Rails Exception Handling Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, controller

I have set up a controller to handle exceptions (404, 522 and 500).

Everything appears to be hooked up correctly and when I hit a page that doesn't exist, at the end of my logs I see the following:

> Processing by ErrorsController#error_404 as HTML Rendered
>   errors/error_404.html.erb within shared/layouts/single_column_layout
>   (0.2ms) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

However I get a generic error message in the browser:

[image]
My Controller looks like this:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html

  layout "shared/layouts/single_column_layout"

  def error_404
    @bad_url = params[:id]
    render status: :not_found
  end

  def error_422
    render status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  def error_500
    render status: :internal_server_error
  end

end
```

In my `development.rb`:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
```

In my `application.rb`:

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

My `routes.rb` contains:

```
  match "/404" => "errors#error_404"
  match "/422" => "errors#error_422"
  match "/500" => "errors#error_500"
```

I have also removed all the static error pages from the `public` directory.

The full stack trace of a 404 is:

> Started GET "/whatever" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-08 14:21:24 +0000
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/downl"):
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in`call'
>   railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'   railties
>   (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in
>   `tagged'   railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in`call'
>   quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in
>   `call_with_quiet_assets'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in`call'   rack
>   (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'   rack (1.4.5)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'   rack
>   (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in`call'   rack-livereload (0.3.15)
>   lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'   rack-livereload (0.3.15)
>   lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in`call'   actionpack (3.2.12)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'   xipio (1.0.0)
>   lib/xipio/middleware.rb:10:in`call'   railties (3.2.12)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'   railties (3.2.12)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:223:in`call'   railties (3.2.12)
>   lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
>
>   /Users/me/Library/Application
>   Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:145:in`
>   handle'   /Users/me/Library/Application
>   Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:99:in
>   `rescue in block (2 levels) in start'   /Users/me/Library/Application
>   Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in`
>   block (2 levels) in start'   /Users/me/Library/Application
>   Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in
>   `each'   /Users/me/Library/Application
>   Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in`
>   block in start'   /Users/me/Library/Application
>   Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in
>   `loop'   /Users/me/Library/Application
>   Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in`
>   start'   /Users/me/Library/Application
>   Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in
>   `run'   /Users/me/Library/Application
>   Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in`
>   '
>
> Processing by ErrorsController#error_404 as HTML   Rendered
>   errors/error_404.html.erb within shared/layouts/single_column_layout
>   (0.3ms) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

Comment: have you added `rescue_from Exception, :with => :handle_exceptions` in ApplicationController and defn for handle_exceptions?

Comment: @emaillenin As far as I understand it, this approach handles the exception on a Rack level and negates the need for handling in `ApplicationController`. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @Barry Sorry. Wish I could remember.